# Probability Distributions $P(A^c\cap B^c)$?

Tags: probability, elementary-probability

How can i do this distribution from Pitman probability textbook? I dont know how this expands. Do i use the compliment rule? Difference rule? Inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: You should give more details regarding what you want (what the problem is asking) and what you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $A^c\cap B^c=(A\cup B)^c$
$$
P(A^c\cap B^c)=1-P(A\cup B)=1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A\cap B).
$$